# Finding the index of elements of the same class but with different parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have elements of the same class but the're wrapped in different parent divs.  How would I go about in finding the index of each `.child` div?

If I were to invoke the index in an iterator I'd get back `0` since its the one and only `.child` present within the parent div. What I'm looking to do is get back index of those divs based within the scope of the `#container` div.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#container .child").text(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    return "The index of this element is " + i
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="one">
    <div class="child"></div>
  <div>

  <div id="two">
    <div class="child"></div>
  <div>

  <div id="three">
    <div class="child"></div>
  <div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `index` you can use the selector and then pass in the element to get the index in the collection

```
$("#container .child").index(this)
```

or even the other way around

```
$(this).index("#container .child")
```

but the easiest is to just use the iterator in the callback function for `text()`

```
$("#container .child").text(function(i) {
    return "The index of this element is " + i
});
```

Comment: In the event that there are let's say, two `#container` divs is there a way to reset the count? So within the second `#container` it would start back from `0` and go up to `2` like it does in the first, instead of going from 1-5?

Comment: There can't be two `#container` divs, ID's are unique.

Comment: But in principle, you'd have to select one of them `$('#container:eq(0) .child')` or iterate with each `$('#container').each(function() { $(this).find('.child')` ... etc.

Comment: That's my mistake. Let's pretend they are `.container`'s instead of `#container`'s.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to your callback function passed to the `.text()` method is the index within the current set.

```
$(function() {
  $("#container .child").text(function(i) {
    return "The index of this element is " + i
  });
});
```